# Can't add "Space" as a shortcut key on a Mac application

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, macos-sierra

I'm trying to add the 'space' key on my keyboard as a shortcut to an app(the app is called "Kite Compositor). I go to *System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts*. I select my application, type the menu title of the app i want to create a shortcut for and at "Keyboard Shortcut" i try to add "Space" as an input by pressing the spacebar.

The problem is that it doesn't register anything. Only key combinations e.g. "Cmd+F". Let's say i want to change the zoom shortcut(which is the 'Z' key on the app) to 'space'. Is there any solution to this?

Comment: So while writing this questions you would have several dozen instances of Kite open? It doesn't sound like a good idea?

Comment: I didn't really understand your comment. What do you mean with "several dozen instances of Kite open"? I just want to change a shortcut. I've done so with Sketch many times. I've assigned and changed like a dozen shortcuts. Right now if you want to 'Pan' around your workspace on Kite you have to press 'C'. I want to change that and use the spacebar.

Comment: What you're describing from my understanding is how to change global shortcut. In addition your description makes it sound like you want to start the application by pressing space. If you want to change an application specific keyboard shortcut the application has to support it. If there is no option to change it within the application you will have to use third party applications.